# Как получить метку времени (UNIX timestamp)?

Tags: javascript

Как можно получить метку времени в JS?

<sup>[Перевод вопроса "How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/221294/6275986)</sup>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
+new Date();
```

Оператор `+` в данном случае приводит операнд к числу, вызывая `valueOf`, на что объект `Date` возвращает временную метку в виде числа (`number`).

---

```
Date.now();
```

Это метод объект `Date`, а не его прототипа для экземпляров, поэтому нет необходимости в создании экземпляра для получения timestamp.
Поддерживается всеми современными браузерами.

---

```
new Date().getTime();
```

Получение метки из экземпляра, так же поддерживается старыми браузерами, поэтому может быть полифиллом там, где нет `Date.now` (не дай Бог, чтобы была необходимость поддерживать столь старые интерпретаторы):

```
if (!Date.now) {
    Date.now = function() { return new Date().getTime(); }
}
```

---

```
new Date().valueOf();
```

Числовое значение объекта, то, что получаем через унарный плюс.

---

Пример работы и конвертация в другие представления:

```js
let timestamp = Date.now();

console.info("Миллисекунды: " + timestamp);
console.info("Секунды: " + timestamp / 1000);
console.info("Минуты: " + timestamp / 1000 / 60);
console.info("Часы: " + timestamp / 1000 / 60 / 60);
console.info("Дни: " + timestamp /1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
console.info("Года: " + timestamp  /1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365);
```

Answer (score 2):

Метод **Date.now()**

> Метод Date.now() возвращает дату сразу в виде миллисекунд.

*Технически, он аналогичен вызову +new Date(), но в отличие от него не создаёт промежуточный объект даты, а поэтому – во много раз быстрее.*

Его использование особенно рекомендуется там, где производительность при работе с датами критична. Обычно это не на веб-страницах, а, к примеру, в разработке игр на JavaScript.

```js
console.log(Date.now());
```

Comment: Позвольте узнать, зачем Вы отвечаете тем, что уже отвечено?

Comment: я раскрыл более подробно, именно по вопросу данную функцию с простым примером, чем было. разве не так? тем более просили просто  метку времени UNIX timestamp, так зачем сюда либу описывать чтобы человек запутался?

Answer (score 0):

Миллисекунды проще всего получить так -

```js
console.log(Date.now()%1000)
```

Comment: А переход на летнее/зимнее время (где он есть) как обрабатывать будем? А [лишнюю секунду раз в год](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)? Время — [это вовсе не так просто](https://habrahabr.ru/post/146109/), чтобы взять монотонные эталонные часы и работать с ними как с обычными.

Comment: И да, речь в вопросе шла **про timestamp**.

Comment: Это вы в соседний ответ напишите. Я всего лишь продемонстрировал, как из временной метки получить миллисекунды

Comment: И что Вы получаете? Миллисекунды и от них модуль числа от 1000?

Comment: @Aid ваш вопрос звучит так - Как получить миллисекунды текущего времени (timestamp)?

Comment: Да. И что Вы получаете? Я бы понял `Date.now / 1000; // Получаем секунды`, но Ваш ответ...

Comment: Мой ответ отвечает на вопрос "Сколько сейчас миллисекунд на часах".  Если вы задавали какой то другой вопрос - то наверное стоит его переформулировать

Comment: Это Вам надо читать вопрос, а не мне изменять его под Вас. Вопрос прост и понятен: Как получить timestamp (количество миллисекунд с 00:00:00 UTC 1 января, 1970 года). А что у Вас возвращается - не то, что нужно.

Comment: "количество миллисекунд текущего времени" и "текущее время в миллисекундах" это разные вещи, не не находите? Если бы речь шла не о миллисекундах, а о часах? "Как получить количество часов текущего времени" больше похоже на "Который сейчас час", а не "сколько прошло времени с 1 января 1970 в часах?"